# xslt - how to specify a single node value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<Tags>
  <Tag TagName="#CC" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="" /> 
  <Tag TagName="#BCC" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="" /> 
  <Tag TagName="#To" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="" /> 
  <Tag TagName="#DocID" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="00000001" /> 
  <Tag TagName="#Date" TagDataType="DateTime" TagValue="20000917213300" /> 
  <Tag TagName="#Subject" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="" /> 
</Tags>


 <xsl:for-each select="Tags/Tag"> <!-- works, give me all tags -->

   <xsl:value-of select="@TagValue" />

 </xsl:for-each>        

<xsl:value-of select="Tags/Tag/@TagValue[1]" /> <!-- doesn't give me anything -
```

When I use the for-each, I get all the TagValues in the order listed.  I now need to display these values in a different order.  So, I abandoned the for-each and tried using the a single statement to get a single value, without success.  How can I specify a specific TagValue to be displayed?  I'm using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want a single TagValue - if so, which one? Or do you want all (non-empty?) TagValues in a specific order - if so, what is the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I now need to display these values in a different order. So, I
>   abandoned the for-each

That makes no sense. If you want "*to display these values in a different order*", you need to **sort** them. Try the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Tags/Tag[string(@TagValue)]">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('#DocID#Date#To#CC#BCC#Subject', @TagName))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <value name="{@TagName}"><xsl:value-of select="@TagValue" /></value>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This takes all non-empty `TagValue` values and sorts them by the following custom order: #DocID, #Date, #To, #CC, #BCC, #Subject. When applied to the following **test input**:

```
<Tags>
    <Tag TagName="#CC" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="" /> 
    <Tag TagName="#BCC" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="bcc recipient" /> 
    <Tag TagName="#To" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="" /> 
    <Tag TagName="#DocID" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="00000001" /> 
    <Tag TagName="#Date" TagDataType="DateTime" TagValue="20000917213300" /> 
    <Tag TagName="#Subject" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="my subject" /> 
</Tags>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <value name="#DocID">00000001</value>
   <value name="#Date">20000917213300</value>
   <value name="#BCC">bcc recipient</value>
   <value name="#Subject">my subject</value>
</output>
```

Comment: This did the job, thanks.  I found that didn't need #DocID, so I removed it from the sort statement, but found it still retrieved it.  I overcame that with encasing the "value-of select TagValue" in a "if position > 1".

Comment: @stevegenovese If you don't need the #DocID value, you can (and should) remove it at the select stage, e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="Tags/Tag[not(@TagName='#DocID')][string(@TagValue)]">`

Comment: That also did the trick, thanks! Like you mentioned yesterday, it sorts all the non-empty tag values.  What I didn't mention yesterday is that I'm displaying the values in a html table, so when it's skips on a empty TagValue, it places the TagValue in the wrong table column.  Is there a way for the for-each to also give me the empty TagValues?

Comment: @stevegenovese I thought that one would be obvious: remove the `[string(@TagValue)]` predicate from the selecting expression.

Comment: What book(s)/website(s) do you recommend for a novice?

Comment: @stevegenovese I'm afraid I am not the right person to ask. But I am sure this question has been asked before.